# Share not working in react native android/ios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I share pdf file link or image link which will open in react native mobile app web browser. I have added a share button but when the user clicks on it, it opens where to share menu options like WhatsApp, Gmail, messages, etc. But when clicking on WhatsApp it does not send any content why so? Do I need to make use of Gmail, WhatsApp API with my react native android app

**code:**

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  Platform,
  Share
} from 'react-native';


// inside render

onSharePress = (shareOptions) => Share.share(shareOptions);

const shareOptions = {
   title: 'Download Brochure',
    url: brochure
}

// inside return 

<View style={{paddingLeft: 10, marginRight: 20, flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onSharePress(shareOptions)}>
         <Icon style={{paddingLeft: 10}} name="md-share" size={25} color="black"/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

In screenshot below you can see it just opens the share options menu but when I click on some of the platform the content i.e the URL of the file is not sent how can I do that ? Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: @harsh Patel Can you please help me with share in react native ? Why is it not working ?

Comment: Sorry to say but I haven't try react JS yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Share.share(content, options)** receives content and options parameter separately.

Share.share(content, options) returns a Promise on both Android and IOS. You basically need to resolve the Promise or read the response from it.

Like so

```
Share.share({
    title:'Some Title',
    // Android
    message: YourURL,
    //ios
    url: YourURL
},{ dialogTitle:"Android Title" })
.then(({action, activityType}) => {
    if(action === Share.sharedAction)
        console.log('Share was successful');
    else
        console.log('Share was dismissed');
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Promise returns an object containing **action, activityType**

If the user dismissed the dialog, the Promise will be resolved with
action being **Share.dismissedAction** else with action being
**Share.sharedAction**

Comment: How can we make this link clickable if its shared on Whatsapp, Skype or SMS?

Answer (score 3):

Read the [friendly `share()` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html#share):

> ## Content
>
> - `message` - a message to share
> - `title` - title of the message
>
> #### iOS
>
> - `url` - an URL to share
>
> At least one of URL and message is required.

So on Android, the `url` option does nothing, and you probably need to put it into `message`.

Answer (score 2):

This is works for me: [Link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/455#issuecomment-520676464)

```
shareApp = () =>{

        let  text = 'Want more buzz around your photos on Insta, Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp posts?\n\nLet\'s make your stories get more eyeballs..\nDownload TagWag App '
        if(Platform.OS === 'android')
            text = text.concat('https://hackeruna.com')
        else
            text = text.concat('http://itunes.apple.com/app/id1453977874')

        Share.share({
            subject: 'Download TagWag App Now',
            title: 'Download TagWag App Now',
            message: text,
            url:'app://tagwag',

        }, {
            // Android only:
            dialogTitle: 'Share TagWag App',
            // iOS only:
            excludedActivityTypes: []
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle promise for this ..

```
 onSharePress = (url) => {
    Share.share({
      title: 'Alert Title',
      message: url + '\nMessage goes here.'
    }).then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

like share text on WhatsApp

> Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${'hello whatsApp'}`);

like share text on Google

> Linking.openURL('https://support.google.com/mail/community');

open your Contact in React Native App

> Linking.openURL('content://com.android.contacts/contacts');

Answer (score 0):

In my case to share `message or url` on Android devices.

Version:  `"react-native": "0.70.2"`

```
export const shareStoredRecords = async () => {
  const message = await getAllStoredRecords();

  try {
    await Share.share({
      message: message,
      url: message,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can work like this

I am accepting values from another component.

```
import { Share } from "react-native";
import * as Sharing from "expo-sharing";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { cacheDirectory, downloadAsync } from "expo-file-system";
const onShare = async (title, message, url, image) => {
    // console.log(image[0])
  const messageAndUrl = message.concat("\n\n").concat(url);
  try {
    url = image[0];
    // console.log({url})
        const uri = await downloadAsync(url , cacheDirectory + "tmp.png");
        // console.log({uri}); // it prints a local image file
        // Share.share({url : uri.uri , message : messageAndUrl });
    const result = await Share.share(
      {
        title,
        url : uri.uri ,
        message: messageAndUrl,
      },
      {
        subject: title,
      }
    );
    if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
      // Always work with android
      if (result.activityType) {
        // worked
      } else {
        // shared
      }
    } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
      // run only for ios if share is dismissed
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default { onShare };
```

## So the result in ios

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

the link is sending as a plaintext in whatsapp but it is working in telegram as a link in android.