# Impossible to share post in linkedin from react native ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, linkedin-api, expo

I use the Share method of react-native to share a message (text with url) on various app. 
In every app I got the right message but when I share it on linkedin on IOS the message is empty.
With android everythings work fine and with other application like discord it works to.

I wanted to try the package react-native-share but since I use expo 34.0.1 I can't use it.

I tried to use the URL parameter but it only share the link and not the message

```js
import {Share} from 'react-native'

await Share.share(
      {
        message: i18n.t('components.shareButton.message'),
      }
    )
```

expo snack for test:
https://snack.expo.io/@slegnaf/impossible-to-share-post-in-linkedin-from-react-native-ios

I expect that when I share the message on linkedin, linkedin post the same message as in an other app, because for now the post is just empty.

Comment: Can you provide expo snack for your question?

Comment: I have edit my post to add expo snack

Comment: Did you try with whatsapp?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045415/share-not-working-in-react-native-android-ios

Comment: it's work with discord or mail but not with linkedin